# Creating an interactive form with a custom list with lookup fields

Tags: custom-list, lookup-column, custom-form

I have a list that we are using to order new computers for staff members.  They fill out all their information, like name department and cost centre.

Then I want them to select from a list of computers to choose from, so I use a lookup field from another list.  Works great, because they can see a drop down of the names of the computers available.

I would like to be able to see the picture that is in that list.  The lookup field doesn't let me choose the picture from the other list.

Any thoughts?  Infopath, script web part?

Comment: is this picture in your other list a URL?

Comment: If you are not looking for a solution where you see the picture right away then Look into the displayrelatedinfo function in SPServices http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Hi Ramana, the picture is an image not a url.  Although the url is a good idea.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is hard to get the image on Drop-down of look up field. But you can try to open the popup or modal window to show the image when clicking / selecting the dropdown.

You can try this with jQuery / JavaScript this way:

```
window.myFunction = function() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100");
    var dd = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    myWindow.document.write(dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
}`
```

Try to write this code on drop-down selection.

Comment: So Mohamed - this would be in SharePoint designer that I would add the script in the NewItem.aspx file and not using the script editor web part?